# OData for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, odata

The `odata` seems promising for Restful API.  However, I couldn't find much information about `odata` library for NodeJS.  Most are from Microsoft's.  Is `odata` not a popular choice for nodian?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-Microsoft [OData server for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-server)